# Linking and Apple receipt to the transaction ID

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

When a customer does an in-app purchase we get the transactionId sent to us from apple and some other information. We have customers sometimes contact us saying they didn't get the item they purchased.

Is there a way to link the information on the customers Apple receipt to the transactionID sent to us? Basically I see no information sent to us from Apple that matches the information on the receipt itself.

Comment: No, there is not. The customer should contact Apple who can issue a refund and You should work out why your in-app purchase isn't delivering. What is the purchase type?  If it isn't a consumable type then all they should end to do is tap the "restore" button in your app.

Comment: It is a consumable item. Problem we are having is we need to be able to link transactions to receipts so we can verify that our system is working.

Comment: As you said in your question, there is no way to link the transaction to the customer's receipt.  You need to make sure your code doesn't complete the in-app purchase transaction until you have successfully persisted the purchase in your app. Also ensure that your app is able to process pending transactions when it launches (register the transaction observer in the app delegate, not just when the user opens the purchase interface)

Comment: Thanks, have to look into some code changes.

Comment: Could we exploit product_id to send some arbitrary data and get it back? Does it appear in Apple invoice?